# How to set the UIKeyboard-Style for the whole App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uiappearance

I am currently trying to set the keyboard style globally, but my approach does not work.
I tried it using `UIAppearance` and put this line of code inside the AppDelegate :

```
[[UITextField appearance] setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

But what I got on the console is the following:

```
[UISearchBarTextField _UIAppearance_setKeyboardAppearance:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa1897e0
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIAppearance` only works with methods that are specifically marked with the macro `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` to be compatible, and unfortunately `keyboardAppearance` is not one of them.

The best way to get what you want is to subclass `UITextField` and set `keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;` in the the subclass's `init` and `initWithFrame:` methods.  Then exclusively use your class wherever you would have used `UITextField` in the app.

Answer (score 8):

iOS7 extended the `UIAppearance` protocol for UITextFields, ergo you can set now the keyboardAppearance on UITextField.

```
[UITextField appearance].keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

However, `UITextView` doesn't support it. For this class, I would go with jszumski's solution

Comment: I tried recently and it doesn't work (iOS 8.2). At least, in conjunction with table views

Comment: Yes! It may cause a crash but you can still set to the textview directly `textView.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;`

Comment: None of these seem to work with UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad